# Why internet Explorer not giving me option to open dwg in trueview like firefox does?

Tags: internet-explorer

Is there a way to make IE behave like Firefox for DWG files? IE just wants to open the file in the browser although the file association states open in TrueView. In IE when I click on the dwg file from SharePoint I get a blank page. But in Firefox it gives an option to open the file with DWG TrueView Application or Save the file.

Can I make IE behave the same way? We can't have firefox for users and IE is the only approved browser. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone please suggest a good solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here....

http://slingeronline.wordpress.com/2008/03/04/the-continuing-saga-of-autodesk-giving-their-users-the-finger/

My TrueView is 2014 so the ID is {6C7DC044-FB1E-4140-9223-052E5ABE7D24}

BACKUP YOUR REGISTRY

1. Go to Registry and find {6C7DC044-FB1E-4140-9223-052E5ABE7D24}
2. Find the subkey under {6C7DC044-FB1E-4140-9223-052E5ABE7D24}
   EnableFullPage
3. Just rename to EnableFullPage-BAK

Close your Registry. Restart Internet Explorer and I should work.